# Simple code to save an excel workbook from within Access works on one computer but not another?

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

Ok, I have searched and searched and have not found an answer.  I have a very simple code that exports the contents of some tables into an excel workbook and then I want to save the workbook in the same directory as the database.  My code works just fine on my computer, but when I try to load the database on a colleague's, the tables export just fine, but the excel workbook will not save as the given name-it just gives a prompt and asks whether you want to save Book1.xlsx  If I disable the messages, it just doesn't save it at all.  (His curDir is different than mine, but I checked and the workbooks aren't in there either) The database was created in Access 2013 and both computers have Access 2013 installed, although the second one (the one that's not working) also has Access and Excel 2010 installed.  The workbook is opening in Excel 2013 though.  I tried changing it to an .xls file and specifying the file format number in the saveas command, but that didn't work.  I am including the code that works on my computer.  I'm sure this is something simple, please help. Oh I should say, it worked fine the first time, but now it won't work (and I deleted the first copy, so I know its not that it doesn't want to overwrite) I'm pulling my hair out!

```
    Public Function DeleteExcessPendragonRecords()
    On Error GoTo DeleteExcessPendragonRecords_err

    Dim strSQL1 As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim osheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strSQLlinkedtables As String
    Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim currdirpath As String

    currdirpath = CurDir()
    'Exporting all tables into Excel Spreadsheet

    Set db = CurrentDb

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Call RefreshSharePointLinks
    strSQLlinkedtables = "SELECT tbl_PendragonTableNames.LocalLink FROM tbl_PendragonTableNames WHERE tbl_PendragonTableNames.ID < 15"

    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQLlinkedtables)
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXL.Visible = True
    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add

   On Error Resume Next

   Do Until rs1.EOF
        oWB.Sheets.Add
        Set osheet = oWB.ActiveSheet
        osheet.Name = rs1.Fields(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim Linkedtable As String
        Linkedtable = rs1.Fields(0)
        Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(Linkedtable)
        For i = 0 To rs2.Fields.Count - 1

            osheet.Cells(1, i + 1).value = rs2.Fields(i).Name

        Next i

            osheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2

        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop
    oWB.SaveAs currdirpath & "\PendragonBackup_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
    rs2.Close
    rs1.Close
    oWB.Close
    oXL.Close
    oXL.Quit
    db.Close


    Set oWB = Nothing
    Set oXL = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    'Code continues after this, but this is the relevant part
```

Comment: Are any errors being thrown?  I see that you are using "On Error Resume Next", which I tend to shy away from because it hides issues.  I would suggest changing the debug settings to break on all errors and test manually.  If an error is being thrown please provide the error and statement that is generating it.

Comment: Hi.  Yes, the on error resume next is mostly for the end user.  I generally comment it out when I am testing it.  I got it do work by adding Dim WBActive as Object , Set WBActive = Active Workbook and then WBActive.SaveAs --the name given above.  But if the code is run in quick succession I get an error 91

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`currdirpath = CurDir()`

try:

`currdirpath = CurrentProject.Path`

Comment: Hi Thanks, I ended up changing that part of the code to specify a specific path anyway--but it still didn't work as written.  I made some changes that I specify in above comments but as I said up there, if the code is run in quick succession, I get error 91